# Start Menu search is very slow in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, start-menu, windows-search, file-search

Not sure what is causing this and was wondering if anyone else had this problem with any way to fix it? It takes about 2-5 seconds after hitting the windows key and starting to type for the search bar on the side to come up. The start menu will appear immediately and I'm running a SSD so I really don't think it is hardware. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a known issue in Windows 8.1. To fix it, add the AppData folder from your user account back to the [Search index](http://web.archive.org/web/20131006214853/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/search-index-faq).

Comment: I'm in indexing options and I hit modify and then Show All Locations in the indexed Locations popup window and under User there isn't an AppData toggle. Am I missing something? Thanks for the response by the way.

Comment: Have you enabled to show hidden files/folders in the Explorer options?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that would change that explorer as well. I thought it only changed the windows explorer application.

Comment: That document you linked helped a bunch.  Just disabling the Bing search seemed to speed things up for me.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did this fix work for you, @jeruntime?

Comment: @Xonatron add the AppData folder to the search index